# Code suddenly stopped working - array not populating

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

This code was working fine 2 weeks ago...suddenly it stopped working and I can't figure out why.

These are the relevant methods that get called in the `viewDidLoad`:

Call in viewDidLoad:

```
if(!self.currentProject.assets){
        [self fetchAssets];
        [self fetchImagesFromAssets:nil];
    }else {
        NSArray *assets = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.currentProject.assets];
        [self fetchImagesFromAssets:assets.mutableCopy];
    }
```

Methods:

```
-(void) fetchAssets{
    self.assets = [[PHFetchResult alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Album Name:%@",self.albumName);


    if (self.albumName.length > 0) {


        PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[self.albumName]    options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *collection = userAlbums[0];

        if (!_isProUser) {

            PHFetchOptions *onlyImagesOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
            onlyImagesOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];

            NSLog(@"Collection:%@", collection.localIdentifier);

            self.assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:onlyImagesOptions];

        }
        else
        {
            self.assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
        }

    }else{

        PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
        options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

        if(!_isProUser){
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
        }

        self.assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
    }
}

-(void) fetchImagesFromAssets:(NSMutableArray*)assets{

    if (assets == nil) {
        assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i = (int)self.firstPhotoIndex; i < (int)self.lastPhotoIndex; i++) {
            [assets addObject:[self.assets objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    self.photosToVideofy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Assets:%lu",(unsigned long)assets.count);

    for (PHAsset *asset in assets)
    {
        if (!_isProUser) {
            [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil
                                       completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                                           NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
                                           NSLog(@"ImageURL:%@", imageURL);
                                           [self.photosToVideofy addObject:imageURL];
                                       }];


        }else{


            if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {

                [self generateImagesFromAsset:asset];


            }else if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeImage){

                [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil
                                           completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                                               NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
                                               [self.photosToVideofy addObject:imageURL];
                                           NSLog(@"ImageURL:%@", imageURL);
                                           }];
            }
        }
    }

    assets = nil;

    NSLog(@"There are %lu photos to Videofy", (unsigned long)self.photosToVideofy.count);
}

-(void) generateImagesFromAsset:(PHAsset *)phAsset{
    NSLog(@"Generating images from video...");
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestAVAssetForVideo:phAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

        AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter =  kCMTimeZero;
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore =  kCMTimeZero;
        generator.maximumSize = self.size;
        int j = 1;
        for (Float64 i = 0; i < CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) *  _FPS ; i++){
            @autoreleasepool {
                CMTime time = CMTimeMake(i, _FPS);
                NSError *err;
                CMTime actualTime;
                CGImageRef image = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];
                UIImage *generatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
                [self saveImage: generatedImage withIndex:self.generatedPhotoIndex]; // Saves the image on document directory and not memory
                CGImageRelease(image);
            }
            j++;
            self.generatedPhotoIndex++;
        }
    }];
}

-(void) saveImage:(UIImage*)image withIndex:(int)index{
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *path = [self documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png",index]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    [pngData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; //Write the file
    NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);
    [self.photosToVideofy addObject:url];

}

-(NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}
```

I narrowed the problem to the `photosToVideofy` array.  It will not populate with the URL's as it should and was 2 weeks ago.

This is the readout of the console:

```
2015-09-03 11:14:44.899 Videofy[885:110958] First:6 Last:175 BPM:120
2015-09-03 11:14:48.891 Videofy[885:110958] Album Name:(null)
2015-09-03 11:14:51.406 Videofy[885:110958] Assets:169
2015-09-03 11:14:51.436 Videofy[885:110958] Generating images from video...
2015-09-03 11:14:51.460 Videofy[885:110958] Generating images from video...
2015-09-03 11:14:51.461 Videofy[885:110958] Generating images from video...
2015-09-03 11:14:51.465 Videofy[885:110958] Generating images from video...
2015-09-03 11:14:51.472 Videofy[885:110958] Generating images from video...
2015-09-03 11:14:51.474 Videofy[885:110958] There are 0 photos to Videofy
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?
(Testing on iPhone 4s and iPad4)

Comment: I would check exactly what the url is returning... it says 169 assets, but maybe they're not video format or something? If they are video format then it may be something of a deeper issue

Comment: @RyanOfCourse The assets are PHAsset objects (images and video) directly from the photo library